# what algorithm is being used in this generative model?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, lstm, generative-adversarial-network

what neural network is used in this generative models code?

```
def make_generator_model():
     model = tf.keras.Sequential()
     model.add(layers.Dense(16, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
     model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
     model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

     model.add(layers.Dense(16))
     assert model.output_shape == (None,16 ) # Note: None is the batch size

     model.add(layers.Dense(32)) # what does 32 denote here
     model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
     model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

     model.add(layers.Dense(32))
     model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
     model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

     model.add(layers.Dense(32))
     model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
     model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

     model.add(layers.Dense(8))
     assert model.output_shape == (None,8 )


     return model
```

this is a code based on the generative adversarial network model. i have a discriminator model also but I need to find out if this generative model is using cnn or lstm or other algorithm to create the generate model.

Comment: Since You don't know what this code is for You probably didn't write it, so that means You pretty much copied it from somewhere else which means that there somewhere else should be written what is this for, no?

Comment: no it wasnt mentioned

Comment: how did You even find this code? because if You were looking for something You would know what You were looking for, otherwise actually You may as well ask the author, or like was this code stranded in the middle of nowhere on internet in a random website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its CNN , If u put your full code it may easy to find

Batch Normalisation maximum used in conventional Neural network only

Comment: How can it be a CNN if there are no convolutional layers?!